# Error: Missing app.json. error in Expo XDE

Tags: react-native, expo

I have developed an app using React-native, now i converted to expo using `exp convert`. I did all the changes to folder which is need (by following steps in  expo-next-steps.txt) but when i run project on expo XDE, i am getting error like 
`Error: Missing app.json.` How to solve this problem? and i used local push notification in react-native app. But in project structure there is file called app.json, still getting this error. i am new to expo, anyone please help me out.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 8):

The expo XDK looks for the expo SDK version in the **app.json** file. Thus, your app.json should look something like :

```
{
  "name": "MyAPP",
  "displayName": "MyAPP",
  "expo": {
  "sdkVersion": "18.0.0"
 }
}
```

Replace the "18.0.0" with your SDK version. 
Such error emerges when you create the app using

```
react-native init
```

instead of

```
create-react-native-app
```

I perceive this as one of the reasons. There may be more such explanations to such occurrences.Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

I deleted the app.json, restarted and it works in my setup.
You might rename it simply to app.json.orig

Comment: Thank you.. i also did the same thing.